# Uploading all university projects into one repository

Tags: git, github

I have collected all the projects and lab exercises I have done in the courses I took at the university in a folder and I want to put them in a single repository called university projects. There are many course folders inside the university projects folder. Inside these course folders there are lab or midterm-final projects folders and many projects in these two folders. For example, the address directory of a project in a course is as follows;

D:\projects\university-projects\mobile-application-development\lab-exercises\lab1-my-first-app

How can I put these university projects in a single repository on Github?

Comment: Does the repo already exist or do you need to create it?  You can put them in there just like you would with any other file.

Comment: @eglease Repo doesn't exist. Even if I create the repo I don't know how to put all projects into the repo.

Comment: You would `commit` the entire directory and `push` it to the repo.  Do you know the commands?  Are you using a particular tool or just command line?

Comment: @eglease Thank you for your answer. I'm using command line and I think I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way you can do this - by using GIT CLI command:

1. Create github repo
2. `git clone <repo_download_link_name>`
3. Move all your folders to this  folder, <repo_name> that has appeared on your terminal
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m "Add university projects"`
6. `git push`

The second way is to use "Github Desktop", that will be in some way easier for you, than steps I have described above.
As I see, you use windows, where github desktop (Application with GUI, that allows you to work with github) is available. You can download it here: https://desktop.github.com/ (or find link in google if you don't trust me).

Download it, login, clone your repo, manually add your directories and make git push

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess there are many ways to do it but you wrote me the simplest way. If you know other ways, I would like to know.